# Android Studio - automatic tag closing - close in new line

Tags: autocomplete, android-studio

Im using Android Studio 0.8.6

I want to change way how tags are automatically closed.

Now it looks like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And I want something like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
```

because when I want to copy last attribute - I can't just select whole line because tag end is there.

I was looking for such option in `File -> Settings -> Editor`, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **File** **->** **Settings** (or click **Ctrl+Alt+S** to go to Settings), expand **Editor** from the drop-down, then expand **Code Style** and click **XML**. Then click **Android** tab from the tabs displayed on the right hand side. Then have a look at the sections - one of them has title: **Layout Files**. Tick the check-box next to **Insert line break after last attribute** within Layout Files section. Click **Apply**, then **OK**, then go to your XML file and reformat code (Ctrl+Alt+S).

Comment: Well, it works for me. But unfortunately the indentation level of `/>` is the same as the one of the attributes, which breaks the whole purpose of clear indication, where a tag ends and it seems like there is no option to fix that!