# XML end tag on its own line

Tags: xml, android-studio, intellij-idea, refactoring

I'm using Android Studio which is based on IntelliJ IDEA.

What I want to use is that put end tag in a new line when I refactor the code.
For example

```
<vendor>IntelliJ</vendor>
```

would change to

```
<vendor>IntelliJ
</vendor>
```

I couldn't find any settings in code style for XML. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is not a setting difference but rather a data difference.

Here, the string value of `vendor` is `"IntelliJ"`:

```
<vendor>IntelliJ</vendor>
```

Here, the string value of `vendor` is `"IntelliJ"` plus an end-of-line character.

```
<vendor>IntelliJ
</vendor>
```

This is not a matter of configuration, preference, or presentation -- the values are different.   (Any given application may choose to trim or normalize a string value, but you're not going to get control over this as a presentation preference.)

Comment: Sorry I provided a wrong example. What I meant was something like ``<item name="foo" />``(/> is in a new line)

Comment: In this new case, you're worried about a difference that makes no difference and is, like your original request, beyond your control.

Comment: yeah semantically makes no difference but that's my employer requirement. isn't there any shortcuts or settings?

Comment: Your employer worries about unconventional and inconsequential matters.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same irritation. Android studios has a setting for this.
(as found in [Android Studio - automatic tag closing - close in new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216008/android-studio-automatic-tag-closing-close-in-new-line/39992818))
go to Settings > Editior > Code style > Android tab > Layout files header
check the box for "insert line break after last attribute"
that will move the closing tag to a new line for you
you can reformat your existing code easily using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (windows)
hope this helps!