# Android studio : How to add end/closing tag automatically in layout xml file

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Where can I find the setting for automatically adding the closing tag in layout XML in Android Studio? For example, if I select TextView from suggestions, it should automatically close it with `/>` .

[image]

I used to get the ending tag automatically, but after updating Android Studio, I am not getting it anymore. I tried searching in `Editor` > `Code Style` > `XML`, but didn't find any relevant setting.

[image]

I am on Android Studio 3.5 RC 3.

Comment: Try the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207367/8043806)

Comment: For me, it just does it by default on Android Studio 3.4.1, and my settings for XML look pretty much the same as yours

Comment: @GiddyNaya I am getting auto complete hints fine , only closing tag is not getting added . I will still try the solution

Comment: @Vucko the option must be some where else , can't find it

Comment: @ManoharReddy Have you tried doing the same in Android Studio 3.4.2?

Comment: XML is just bad. Closing tags (or even self-closing) are inconsistent and error-prone. Wish there was an alternative for Android layout files.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39992818/13685592) StackOverflow answer.

Comment: @KalanaChinthaka No use

Answer (score 2):

Could it be this one?

[image: Android Studio Settings]

`Insert closing tag on tag completion` and `Auto-close tag on typing </` ?

For what is worth, mine closes automatically.

Comment: It must be that one! Good catch. Mine is also turned on and it does close the tag.

Comment: Mine is checked too but still the ending tag does not come

Answer (score 1):

I've both AD 3.4.2 and 3.5 RC 3 installed on my system. XML issues like this are only happening on 3.5+ versions. I've looked up at open issues and came to know that 3.5 causing many issues like [No auto tags after completion](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130638004), [hangs/freezes during autocompletion](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133864394) and many more.

Comment: ya might be a bug , I cannot find any setting . I will accept answer once I can confirm if  it's a bug .

Answer (score 0):

**The base problem:** Observe the current code style (Schema) [it's got changed from default style to project style when you rebuild your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55656805/how-to-save-code-style-in-android-studio-forever), I don't know why this happened!

A proper fix for this, is setting the current style to *Default IDE*:

[image]